# Processing an extremly large number in python

Tags: python, numpy, math, nvidia, numba

I am trying to test a theory on the biggest known prime number, that is larger than sys.maxsize:
2**77232917-1

I tried to find a library but there is no suitable answer.
should I use another math theory that deals with smaller numbers in python and can be applied on that number?
or how did they found that number using computer in the first place?

code I've tried:

```
from numba import jit, cuda, vectorize, float64, int64
import numpy as np
import math

# c0= int(input('input a positive integer:'))

#@vectorize([int64], target ="cuda")

@jit
def func1(c0):
    counter=0
    while True:
        if c0%2 == 0:
            c0 = c0/2
        elif c0 == 1:
            break
        elif c0%2 != 0:
            c0 = 3 * c0 + 1
        counter = counter + 1
        print(c0)
    print(counter)

# (2**77232917-1)
#c1 = math.ldexp(1,77232917)


c1 = 2**77232917
b1 = c1 - 1
func1(b1)
```

errors:

```
OverflowError: math range error
```

Note: I am new to numba, I thought by using it, I might solve this issue.

Comment: To find these numbers, the Lucas-Lehmer tests have been used alongside ECPP (Elliptic Curve Primality Proving). I presume you are trying the Collatz conjecture on it? Yeah, Python probably isn't fast enough to do that and the number of iterations it would take would not be feasible on a simple computer.

Comment: Thank you @ArvinKushwaha for the comment. But could you suggest an architecture?

Comment: What do you mean by architecture in this context?

Comment: I mean cpu and ram that permit this kind of computations.

Comment: I don't think CPUs fast enough to solve this problem exist yet.